# CUBA Platform Frontend UI update model doesn't work

Tags: cuba-platform

I needed to update backend model, so I entered the npm run update-model command but it returns an error:

```
events.js:292
throw er; // Unhandled ‘error’ event
^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:*****
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
Emitted ‘error’ event on ClientRequest instance at:
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
errno: -61,
code: ‘ECONNREFUSED’,
syscall: ‘connect’,
address: ‘127.0.0.1’,
port: ******
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project2 update-model: gen-cuba-front sdk:all --dest src/cuba
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project2 update-model script.
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably in Studio integration flag isn't turned on.
Use main menu -> File -> Settings -> CUBA -> Enable integration.
[image]